# Regular Expression for extracting POP3 headers

Tags: regex, pop3

I'm trying to work out how to extract POP3 headers using this regex

^(?[a-zA-Z-]+)(?(?=:).+)$

Delivered-To: yer@ner.com

The group  returns the ':' character as well which I want to avoid. I'm busting trying to work this out but can't.

Need collective wisdom :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like

```
/^([^:]+):(.*)$/
```

Then you would have

- $1 - header name
- $2 - value

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a very common trick which can be used for many situations

Comment: I would make the [^:]+ character class possessive, in order to prevent possible needless backtracking: [^:]++

Answer (score 2):

Just so you are aware, this will not handle wrapped headers. In fact, that regex will take a wrapped header, and prepend it to a real header. Especially if the wrapped header doesn't have a ":" in the following lines.

Building upon Sergej Andrejev's Regex, this one will handle not capturing the wrapped lines:

```
^([^:\s+]+):(.*)$
```

However, the best thing to do, is to actually read the headers line by line, and parse accordingly. It's a pain (as I've had to do it for production code), but it's the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, copied the wrong code: 
^(\S+):\s((\s\S)*)
It works with multi lines.

Comment: That regex is not going to work at all. Its syntax is invalid to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong code: 
^(\S+):\s(([\s\S](?!^(\S+):))*) 

It works with multi lines.